# read more, even if excerpt not trimmed

Tags: hooks, excerpt, read-more

I am using the excerpt field (Not the tag, because the excerpt also serves as a lead paragraph). I altered the "more"-link to be an arrow >.

```
function fabs_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' <a class="more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">></a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'fabs_excerpt_more' );
```

But it only appears, if the excerpt is trimmed down. I also tried this:

```
function fabs_excerpt_more($output) {
 global $post;
 return $output . '<a class="more" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">></a>';
}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'fabs_excerpt_more' );
```

In that case the > appears for every excerpt, but after the closing p-tag. Is there a way to let it appear directly after the last word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a simple string replacement. The following is untested:

```
    function fabs_excerpt_more($output) {
     global $post;
$output = str_replace('</p>', '<a class="more" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">></a></p>', $output);
     return $output;
    }
    add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'fabs_excerpt_more' );
```